# Removing punctuations in dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, string, nlp, punctuation

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
  A        B       C       D      E
0 Orange  Dad's  X Eyes   3d.    Navy
1 pink.   Mum's  Bored.   ooo.   NaN
2 Yellow  NaN    Sad      Gray   NaN
```

I'm trying to remove punctuations in every column in the dataframe using for loop

```
import string
string.punctuation

#defining the function to remove punctuation
def remove_punctuation(text):
    punctuationfree="".join([i for i in text if i not in string.punctuation])
    return punctuationfree

#storing the puntuation free text
col=['A','B','C','D','E']

for i in col:
    df[i].apply(lambda x:remove_punctuation(x))
```

But I get

```
    "TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    /var/folders/jd/lln92nb4p01g8grr0000gn/T/ipykernel_24651/2417883.py in <module>
         12 
         13 for i in col:
    ---> 14     df[i].apply(lambda x:remove_punctuation(x))
      
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"
```

Can anyone help me on this please? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Avoid the loop and try `df.stack().str.replace('.', '', regex=False).unstack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because of `NaN` values, try to check for `NaN` upfront:

```py
def remove_punctuation(text):
    if pd.isna(text):
        return text
    punctuationfree="".join([i for i in text if i not in string.punctuation])
    return punctuationfree

for c in df:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(remove_punctuation)
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
# df
          A     B       C     D     E
0   Orange   Dads  X Eyes    3d  Navy
1     pink   Mums   Bored   ooo   NaN
2   Yellow   NaN     Sad  Gray   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have some float values in your dataframe.

So maybe try to remove them, or in the `remove_punctuation` function::

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
    punctuationfree= "".join([i for i in text if i not in string.punctuation]) if isinstance(text, str) else text
    return punctuationfree
```

Which tests if `text` is a `string` otherwise return it as is

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Orange' , "pink.",  "Yellow"],"B":["3d.", "Boared","%hgh&12"]})

for column in df:
     df[column]=df[column].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
```

your output will look like this:

```
       A        B
0     Orange    3d
1     pink   Boared
2    Yellow  hgh12
```